# Как сделать индивидуальную переменную в телеграм боте для каждого пользователя, переменная по начислению очков в телеграм боте игре?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
pts = 0
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    global pts
    if callback.data == 'otvet':
        pts += 1
        n = 1
        bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "✅Правильно, перейти к /level" + str(n + 1))
        bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Количество очков:" + str(pts))
```

Comment: По хорошему в архитектуре, где мы должны учитывать собственные параметры для каждого юзера, нужно использовать базу данных с отношением пользователь->параметр, подойдёт любая sql. Тем не менее вы можете создать список/словарь значений, где ключём будет выступать `user_id`, и прилагающими к нему параметрами, в вашем случае `pts`

Answer (score 0):

Если вам прямо так надо создать переменную с именем пользователя:

```
exec(f'{name}=0')
```

Можно и так:

```
globals().__setitem__(name, 0)
```